# Only ipv6 available after cable switch

Tags: networking, router, ipv6, cat6

Tried to move my ISP router (ZXHN H298A V1.0) to  a new location with cat6a cables (patch cords) and DELOCK 86166 keystone modules.
The layout is like this router > cat6a > keystone > cat5e (T-568B) > pc
After I added the extension my PC now has only ipv6 address ([ifconfig result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Bat0.png)) and no internet access.
If I link my pc directly to cat6 it's working just fine.
As far as I know 6a has backwards compatibility with 5e.

Comment: The issue seems to be with the keystone, tried with 6a > keystone > 6a and I get the same result, initially thought the issue was about the wiring.

Comment: Get a single cable long enough so you don't need to use a keystone. Backwards compatibility does not change the fact these cables are different and using them in series is a sure recipe for connection issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was the router, I was testing my connection on port 4 (was the only one free).
after many calls to my isp, found I found out that port 4 is for poe... oh well you live and learn.